# Why there is NaN when i'm trying feed raw data txt through pandas to python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am beginner in python. I want to feed my raw data from txt to python through pandas. 
This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('moji/set1.txt', delimiter = ',')
```

I don't understand Why there is NaN in the result ?

this is my 
[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jm19.png)
and this is the
[import pandas result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0KDa.png)

UPDATED
 with the explanation from the answer in below , i rewrite my code with below

```
pd.read_csv('moji/set1.txt', delimiter = ',' , usecols[0,1,2,3])
```

Comment: because there is comma at the end of each line in your raw data.

Comment: thank you for you response, i understand it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@alec_a is correct just to chip in saying how to solve it, without editing data, you would have to use `drop`:

```
df = df.drop('Unnamed: 4', 1)
```

Then now:

```
print(df)
```

Would be outputted as expected.

Comment: thank you for your response. I try by using usecols=[0,1,2,3] and it worked.